# SIM800L power state

Tags: arduino, at-command

What is the best way to (programatically) detect whether my SIM800L module is powered up already?

I'm having issues with the module "switching itself" on sometimes, so my sketch cannot assume that the module is switched off by default ( or vice versa). I tried issuing an AT command and check for OK, and only if no reply do I try to toggle power, but it is not giving the desired results.

Comment: How exactly is your attempt to query via an AT command failing?  One would expect that if it is off you would never get any response, and if it is on you would get something from a command which should have a response, but possibly something other than the expected response if you get the synchronization between commands and their responses mixed up.

Comment: Hi Chris, it seems the issue is somewhat temperamental. It may actually be my LiPo battery that is causing the issues - it looks like when the battery runs low, the unit will still try to switch on, but only for about 5 seconds, then switch off.

Comment: PS - there is also an "IR" pin on my module that is supposed to show whether the unit is on or off - but it is not clear whether it is a digital or analogue signal, or whether it is low or high when on/off - all my attempts thus far to detect have failed.